# C# Do something right after BackgroundWorker RunWorkerCompleted finishes

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a C# project (.NET 3.5) which uses a `BackgroundWorker` to do some stuff.
This stuff writes a log file for all the operations it performs. When the `BackgroundWorker` 
is done, I need to retrieve some information that is in the log file. The problem is that
When the `RunWorkerCompleted` event is fired, the log file is still empty. So if I do the following:

```
private void BackProgress_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
      LoadLog();

}
```

The `LoadLog` method will find an empty log.

I have been debugging the application and I found that the log file is no longer empty in the exact moment the last curly brace in `RunWorkerCompleted` is hit. I don't know how I can load the log file in the appropriate moment because anything I do right after the call to `RunWorkerAsync()` would be executed immediately and the `BackgroundWorker`'s work still wouldn't be finished (again, an empty log).

Basically I need to be able to call `LoadLog` right AFTER the `RunWorkerCompleted` method reaches its end.

Do you have any idea that could help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you show us what the `DoWork` handler looks like?

Comment: This almost sounds like a log flushing problem, maybe look at whatever logging system you are using and see if there is a flush call or autoflush or something.

Comment: You could put the code in the worker thread, you can use a true/false flag to indicate when the worker thread is finished.  If you still have a handle to the thread you can check to see if the thread is alive before attempting to read. if the file is open then it is locked and you could check that as well.

Comment: How you write to log file? DOes you Flash/Close your file before opening in `BackProgress_RunWorkerCompleted`?

Comment: the best way to save a text file is using a `StreamWriter` class in a using statement. then you are also sure that the file has been closed after the worker has been finished

Comment: The DoWork handler calls a function called SendMail() which has a for loop. In each iteration it uses a new thread to run a lambda function that will send an email. Once all the emails have been sent, the runworkercompleted event is fired.

Comment: To write the log, a StreamWriter is used like this: 
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("name.txt", true))
            {
                file.WriteLine(message);
            }

Comment: Most likely a lack of `Flush()`. Second candidate is something that was run with `Invoke()`.

Comment: I set a breakpoint in RunWorkerCompleted and another one in the line that writes to the log. Surprisingly, the WorkerCompleted was hit first and then the other line was hit a lot more times than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Control/Form [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) Method to call LoadLog asynchronously.

This method uses PostMessage to put a registered message on the windows message queue and returns immediately - that’s how it makes the async call.

Like this:

```
BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(LoadLog));
```

Comment: This works from the second time I do the whole thing. The problem is that it should work since the first time (Nobody wants to send duplicate emails). Before adding this code, the log wasn't loaded the first time, then it was loaded the second one, the third one not, and so on. Now it is loaded everytime starting from the second one. Still, the one that matters is the first one. :/

Comment: What happens first time? Is the log empty? When is the log not empty after the first run? Sorry for the questions, I'm trying to understand the problem.

Comment: It's ok. The first time the log is empty, because (as I understand) the LoadLog method is called before the bw is done. The log stops being empty just when the last curly brace in runworkercomplete is passed.

Comment: Do you call `BeginInvoke ` from `BackProgress_RunWorkerCompleted`?  With `BeginInvoke ` `BackProgress_RunWorkerCompleted` should pass before `LoadLog`.

Comment: Right now I am using BeginInvoke in BackProgress_RunWorkerCompleted to call LoadLog. Not working as expected, though.

Comment: That means that the other thread still writes to log even after the RunWorkerCompleted. Try to block the BackgroundWorker thread until the other thread terminates. E.g [Thread.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx) method.